# VBA in excel not printing any information after I used If Value <> Null Then

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have tried to move test results from a UserForm to a database tab but the only one that shows up correct is test one. Test two and three show the power.values but not the equation. I have tried changing <> 0 to <> null but nothing changes it.

```
    'Test1 Results
    .Cells(iRow, 21).Value = Weight1.Value / Time1.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 24).Value = Power1.Value

    If Weight2.Value <> 0 Then
    .Cells(iRow, 26).Value = Weight2.Value / Time2.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 29).Value = Power2.Value
    End If

    If Weight3.Value <> 0 Then
    .Cells(iRow, 31).Value = Weight3.Value / Time3.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 34).Value = Power3.Value
    End If
```

Comment: What is the value of `Weight2.Value` and `Weight3.Value`? Debug your code by going through it step by step (with F8) and check the values. Check [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html).

Comment: Weight2.Value and Weight3.Value can be any whole number @Pᴇʜ

Comment: But what is the exact value/number when the code fails? Debug like I explained above or use `Debug.Print Weight2.Value` to print the value into the intermediate window. Also what is `Weight2`? A textbox? or how is it defined?

Comment: Is not there an `On error goto something` and a division by 0?

Comment: Any number entered into the textbox fails. I thought maybe that by putting null it  assigned the entered value a text format but after I changed it to <> 0 the same issue occured.

Comment: you probably need to convert it into a number `cInt(Weight2.Value)` or `val(Weight2.Value)` or anything like that depending what type of numbers you input.